# How to fetch user current location and some other coordinate are same or not?

Tags: ios, google-maps, maps, mapkit, mapbox

I want to match user current location with other location whether they are same or not.

**My logic:**

```
            point.coordinate = coordinate
            let userLat = mapView.userLocation?.coordinate.latitude
            let userLong = mapView.userLocation?.coordinate.longitude
            if point.coordinate.latitude == userLat && point.coordinate.longitude == userLong
            {
            point.title = "You are here"

            }
            else
            {
            point.title = "\(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)"
            }
```

But the probelm is that, `mapView.userLocation?.coordinate.latitude` is not equal to `point.coordinate.latitude` . However I am setting the same value for userLocation in simulator and other cooridinate.

**Value I am setting for User Location is:**
Lat : 28.6
Long : 77.35

**Value I am setting for other coordinate is:**
Lat : 28.6
Long : 77.35

**Value I am getting for User Location is:**
Lat: Optional
  - Some : 3.4028234663852886e+38

Long:▿ Optional
  - Some : 3.4028234663852886e+38

**Value I am getting for other coordinate is:**
Lat : 28.6
Long : 77.35

And if there is any better logic to find out this thing , then please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your point object - object of CLLocation subclass? If not, create CLLocation from your point.coordinate and compare as below.
Try this compare CLLocation objects, instead of coordinates, using this approach:

```
let distanceThreshold: CLLocationDistance = 2.0 // in meters
if point.distanceFromLocation(mapView.userLocation!) < distanceThreshold {
point.title = "You are here"
} else {
point.title = "\(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)"
}
```

or you can set threshold to 0